# Why does Bcrypt keep failing with MySQL, and how do I retrieve the hash?

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I am trying to take a password from React Native into Flask via URL and then insert it into MySQL. I then retrieve it from DB and test it against the password. I've tried every combination of making the hash and password strings and encoded utf8 but I only ever get false, please let me know what's wrong.

my get password method that hashes and inserts into DB

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET'])
def signup():
    password = str(request.args.get('password')).encode('utf8')
    username = str(request.args.get('username')).encode('utf8')
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO profiles 
                      (username, password
                           )
                      VALUES 
                      (%s, %s)""", ## gender true==male && false==female
                      (username, hashed
                       )
                    )
        con.commit()
```

I get a row in mysql looking like this (varchar256)

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| password                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| $2b$12$oD607B1ej5qXM/mFcPVdueX8R5zeWNfL39d2oNPuoM3KdUfP8McvO |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

my retrieve password method

```
@app.route('/check_hash', methods=['GET'])
def check_hash():

    try:
        username = request.args.get('username')   
        password = str(request.args.get('password')).encode("utf8")

        c.execute('select password from profiles where userID = ' + '"'          + str(username) +'"')

        hashed = (c.fetchone()[0]).encode('utf8')

        if bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == (hashed):          
            return json.dumps('success')
        else:        
            return json.dumps('no')

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Failed every time with false when expected is true

Comment: Try returning the value of both `bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed)` and `(hashed)` and see their difference. In `signup()`, where do you generate the hash?

Comment: Does it actually fail and return "no"? Have you checked that it doesn't return an Exception-message? I tried running your code by generating the hash with `hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())`, and it works.

Comment: Hi thanks a ton for the reply. I did run it just by taking URL and entering it on safari, and I do get the return message 'no'. The return of crypt.hashpw(password, hashed) is : "b'$2b$12$oD607B1ej5qXM/mFcPVdueoNoOExCqr.NF7FOvVCHQ9ZhBTh1Kqwu'" and the return for just hashed is "b'$2b$12$oD607B1ej5qXM/mFcPVdueX8R5zeWNfL39d2oNPuoM3KdUfP8McvO'"

Comment: so (hashed) is right as it just returns the database hash, but for some reason the crypt.hashpw isn't working right, the password I enter is proper, so I'm wondering if changing the format of the password is what is causing this with str() and .encode()

Comment: Yes, try verifying that the password is sent and handled exactly the same way in the two methods. Also, you insert into the DB regardless if the user already exists. Perhaps ensure you don't have another user with the same username, but different password (clear the DB perhaps?). A debugger might be of more help otherwise.

Comment: thanks a lot I found out that it wasn't the code that was wrong it was that I was calling the URL with fetch in react native and inserting data differently than the way I was calling the hash URL to check passwords. For my trials I set the data with react, then tested the hash over a URL in safari. When I switched both to react native it worked, so you were right it was an error with making sure the password was send and handled the exact same way. Thank you!